# Terminating Employement Contract which you never received in original

Tags: contracts, termination

I recently signed an employment contract in Germany, with a consultancy firm in Germany. I did not mention my address in Germany to them. One week later, I informed them about not joining them and terminating the contract. They told me I cannot quit now, as breaking the contract is not possible before the joining date and threatened me to face legal actions and penalties. I still haven't received any original contract letter by post and I haven't responded to their emails asking for an address. What is my way out? Please help me, what can I do to get out of this? What amount I should have to pay in such a case to get out of this mess?

Comment: I don't know how to say "talk to a lawyer" in German, but that's what you need to do.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. You signed the paper, like in their office, and they were about to send you a copy by post after somebody else sign?

Comment: Yes I signed the contract letter in the consultancy office but I was not gureenteed that I have the job. Later to that they called me that I have this job . Now I have emailed them that I have personal family issues and I wish not to work for them anymore. They asked me suggest a new person if any and sent me a copy of contract letter via email. (no original received). I have emailed them that I don't wish to continue with this contract. Later they called me that you might face legal issues if you do not join us. I called requested them to not to act legally and spoil my career.

Comment: Did you sign an "Arbeitsvertrag" or not?

Comment: Yes they asked me to sign that as well , Arbeitsvertrag . What exactly is that ? I have signed it :(

Comment: I do not have a resident permit yet from Germany , I would need employment contract in original in case I need to apply for blue card, I am back to my home country. I am not sure what should I do now? Can there be any complications?

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: "Sprechen Sie mit einem Anwalt". Roger: "What exactly is that? I have signed it. " Oh shit. You signed an employment contract and are in breach of it. In Germany that's not a thing that people do. On the other hand, chances of getting money out of you when you have none and are in a foreign country are slim. So I would assume the company will do what they can to frighten you as much as possible as long as it doesn't cost them money.

Answer (score 3):

If you already signed the contract, of your own free will and without duress, then you are bound by its terms.  Period.

Refusing to give them your address or answer their emails only prevents them from sending you *your copy of the contract,* it doesn't prevent from you from being sued out the arse for breach of contract if you violate the terms within.

You need to talk to a lawyer.  You also probably *want a copy of that contract* to *show to the lawyer,* so it would probably behoove you to let them send you your copy.  Although you *could* talk to the lawyer first, if you really want to.

Comment: Thanks Steve, for for your response. Do you know the worst case how much money I would have pay? 2 months salary or something? Do they have power to take legal action which can affect my personal life? I am really worried?

Comment: @Roger You have to read the contract and know the law, hence the advice to ask a lawyer.

Comment: BTW. If they take you to court in Germany and win, they will be able to get the money from you if you are anywhere in the EU.

Comment: I am out of EU already , do you think they will still want to put a court case on me?

Comment: @Roger: Since you are not going to turn up in court, winning the case is very, very little effort. Judge: "Employee what do you say?" "Roger is in breach of his contract. " Judge: "Roger, what do you say? I see your'e not here, so you are in breach of your contract". Sort this if you ever want to return to Europe. All depends on how annoyed they are and how nasty they want to be. You doing a runner will make them _very_ annoyed.

Comment: I am in good terms with them , I called them and explained my personal problem. I got a email from them asking if "I can suggest a replacement person for my position " I replied them suggesting a persons name who is interested. I hope they have no intentions taking this forward in court anymore.. But do I have to formally terminate the contract with a letter via post or just email communication is fine?

Comment: @Roger If you don't want to ask a lawyer at least ask them for something in writing confirming that you've terminated your contract. E-mail/PDF may be fine too.

Comment: Hello Brandin, i tried asking that too , they rejected it.