# Terminating German Emplyoment Contract after 1 week of signing

Tags: contracts, termination, germany

I signed a contract with A German engineering consultant for 11 Sept 2017 joining . I informed them about not joining the office due personal family issues (email).

The probation period is 6 months and 2 months notice period in that. It's also written in contract that terminating contract before the joining is not possible. 
How much money in this case I have to pay to employer? Any experiences ? I just wanted to know legally in a general German employment contract how much money we have to pay? 2 months salary or 1 year salary? Full /Half?Since I don't want to spoil my career I wish to pay money and get out of this?I just want to get an basic idea of money I need to pay for this. 
I am not a German national, I am on work visa and I am on a fixed contract with a big company in Germany till Dec 17. Do my current employment faces some danger due to this issue? 
What would be the legal course and procedure in such a case , do I get arrested or something? Can they charge me a bill or invoice at my address or put a notice to visit court for hearing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminating Employement Contract which you never received in original](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92937/terminating-employement-contract-which-you-never-received-in-original). The current one is better formulated.

Comment: Yes , just a duplicate:) , sorry but I am in confused state of mind , hence asking repeated questions to get clarification on a foreign land .. it's of a great help when you guys reply with positivity and sense

Comment: IANAL but **2 months** notice period seems strange, usually it is **2 weeks**, which is also backed up by the BGB (Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch) §622 (3): "Während einer vereinbarten Probezeit, längstens für die Dauer von sechs Monaten, kann das Arbeitsverhältnis mit einer Frist von zwei Wochen gekündigt werden." which roughly translates to: "During a 6 months probation period, the notice period is 2 weeks". If it is not explicitely stated otherwise in your contract, 2 weeks is your number.

Comment: The notice period is not mentioned in the contract during probation period. It says the mutual agreed notice period would be decided my mutual consent with both parties. If the notice period is 2 weeks and I resign on first day , will it be fine? Do I need to serve for complete 14 days ?

Answer (score 4):

They cannot do *anything* or *enforce anything* without taking you to court. If they do, the court will notify you. But they won't.

Most of the time, as long as you stay in touch and explain why you cannot fulfill your duties as outlined in the contract, they'll just let you go. Because going to court involves costs for lawyers and right now, they would only *pay* for dragging you to court. No matter the outcome, you will not work for them, so it does not make sense to go after you and pay a lawyer for it. That lawyer will cost more than they will ever get from you. Best case for *them*, the court might rule that you need to pay for their time interviewing you and for their time to find a replacement for you. And that ruling will be 2 years down the road when courts have time for it. But their lawyer will bill them *now*.

So call them or set up a meeting. Tell them you are sorry, something unexpected came up since you signed, a family emergency and you cannot start in September. If appropriate in your situation, you could ask for a later start date or ask to have the contract nullified altogether. Most likely they will be grumpy but understanding. They don't have another sensible option.

This should not affect any other employment contracts you have with different companies. Obviously, the company you should have started for in September might never consider you again, but emergencies happen, this should not have any impact on your career with other employers or work visas that depend on other employers.

Comment: Dear Nvoigt , thanks a a lot for such a detailed explanation and answer! I am very very thankful to you for helping me out :) . I would do exactly as suggested by you !

Comment: I don't wish to work with that company any more , also the company has my native address from my home country ( non EU nation) . Also I haven't received any contract letter in original from this company via post as they do not have my German address . I emailed them that I want to come out of this contract due to personal reasons and I wish not to continue with them. They replied asking me if any recommendations for other people for the same job and sent me a copy of my signed contract letter (soft copy). Do you think there might be still some chance of facing legal action in such a case now ?

Comment: I would say the chances are low. The company has nothing to gain from dragging you to court.

Comment: The contract letter says "Beginn und Dauer, Probezeit, Kündigung Das Vertragsverhältnis beginnt mit dem 18.09 2017 Der Arbeitnehmer hat auch vor Antritt des Vertragsverhältnisses den Arbeitgeber über etwaige Verhinderungen rechtzeitig zu informieren. Der Vertrag gilt auch dann als rechtmaßig zustande gekommen, wenn der Arbeitnehmer am ersten Arbeitstag der Benachrichtigungspficht aus Gründen von höherer Gewalt nicht nachgekommen ist und dies unverzüglich nach Wegfall des Hinderungsgrundes nachholt. What do you think of this ? Also 2 months notice during probation period also is not common..